# Invalid `prisma.dayEvent.create()` invocation: Null constraint violation on the fields: (`id`)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prisma, supabase, trpc

When I'm trying to create event in calendar this error throws:

```bash
Invalid `prisma.dayEvent.create()` invocation:

Null constraint violation on the fields: (`id`)
```

Which is weird cause id have default() in prisma schema

Prisma schema:

```
model Calendar {
  id           String      @id @default(cuid())
  calendarName String
  dayEvents    dayEvent[]
  hostId       String

  host User @relation(fields: [hostId], references: [id])
}

model dayEvent {
  id         String   @id @default(cuid())
  name       String
  date       DateTime
  calendarId String

  calendar   Calendar @relation(fields: [calendarId], references: [id])
}
```

TRPC code where is prisma.create() triggering error:

```js
create: protectedProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({ name: z.string(), date: z.date(), calendarId: z.string() })
    )
    .mutation(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      return ctx.prisma.dayEvent.create({ //Error here
        data: {
          name: input.name,
          date: input.date,
          calendarId: input.calendarId,
        },
      })
    }),
```

In Calendar `@id @default(cuid())` is working, I can create calendars.
But for some reason in dayEvent it wants id.
When I give it id, like that:

```
create: protectedProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({ name: z.string(), date: z.date(), calendarId: z.string() })
    )
    .mutation(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      return ctx.prisma.dayEvent.create({
        data: {
          id: '1',
          name: input.name,
          date: input.date,
          calendarId: input.calendarId,
        },
      })
    }),
```

Everything is working as expected. Despite this, I don't think it will be right to generate ids like that with trpc.

Using full t3 stack

I searched on the web, but didn't find anything helpful.
Did `npx prisma db push` to make sure database is in sync with the Prisma schema.

Comment: Is this mongoDb?

Comment: This is supabase

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is on the schema.

This is the docs example in the one to many relation:

```
model User {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  posts Post[]
}

model Post {
  id       Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  author   User @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId Int
}
```

**If you have a one to many relation:** The problem in your code is here:

```
calendar   Calendar @relation(fields: [id], references: [id])
```

You should change fields **[id] to fields [calendarId].**

In the Calendar you should change the day DayEvent to days DayEvent[]

**But** if you have one to one relation this field should be @unique in the schema.

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks for responding, but sadly It's not working as expected. I edited question for better understanding of situation. Right now I'm generating ids with uuid().

Comment: Seeing your edit two considerations:

`
create: protectedProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({ name: z.string(), date: z.date(), calendarId: z.string() })
    )
    .mutation(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      return ctx.prisma.dayEvent.create({
        data: {
          id: '1',
          name: input.name,
          date: input.date,
          calendarId: input.calendarId,
        },
      })
    }),
`

1.  The id is marked as default, you dont need to send it.

1. The calendarId corresponds with one already created in the other table?